# Concurrent Algorithmic Thinking and learning it in Go

Tags: concurrency, go

I have a history of studying and practicing standard, sequential
algorithms and I've reached a fair degree of comfort with them.
However, I have next to zero experience with concurrent programming
and thinking concurrently.

From a sequential point of view, Go looks like an extremely fun
language to work with. However, besides the Go tutorial and Effective
Go which already assume prior knowledge of concurrent programming, I
really don't know where to begin learning concurrent programming
skills well enough so that I can effectively use Go's support for
them.

Could anybody tell me a good place to start (besides the tutorial)?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf - that's what Rob Pike recommends.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, must have skipped it before :/